# How to show seconds in time format of KDE lock screen?

Tags: kde, date, time, qt, sddm

I am using Russian locale and I use KDE. When locking screen with Meta + L, you see the current date and time on it. The time is in format "12:34". I want to change it to "12:34:56".
I tried to change locale to C, and it worked for seconds. But the day names and month names  becomes in English.

Is it possible to use seconds in lock screen, while keeping all text in Russian?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.
Open '/usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel/org.kde.breeze.desktop/contents/components/Clock.qml' with root rights, then edit this line:
`text: Qt.formatTime(timeSource.data["Local"]["DateTime"])`
to this:
`text: Qt.formatTime(timeSource.data["Local"]["DateTime"], "hh:mm:ss")`

The same edit may be done for SDDM login screen. Its file is '/usr/share/sddm/themes/breeze/components/Clock.qml'.

See also: [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783184/how-to-display-kde-lock-screen-time-in-24-hour-format) and [kde forum discussion](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=130484).

I do not know why qt shows seconds for C locale. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74523059/why-qt-formattime-in-shortformat-is-different-for-similar-locales).

Comment: Answered in the s